# How do I set language in GoKGS?

Tags: go, kgs

I am forced to use czech language, but I would like to use English. How can I switch languages in GoKGS?

This is what I see when I click File (1st in the menu) and Set preferences (3rd in the submenu):

[image]

I don't see anything to switch languages. My preferences should probably look like in the help page (https://www.gokgs.com/help/setPrefsWin.html) but unfortunatelly they don't!

Comment: Are you using the applet or webstart?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I am using applet. What is webstart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I ran it directly from the page: https://www.gokgs.com/applet.jsp - this doesn't allow to change the language (options are reduced).

Once I downloaded and installed CGoban3 at my computer (https://www.gokgs.com/download.jsp), it works as expected and I can change the language.

Answer (score 0):

CGoban v3.3.19 Working ok for me. Check version, update, if that doesn't work, consider contacting https://www.gokgs.com/help/faq/index.html#morequestions

[image]

Comment: I didn't have it as because I was using an applet directly from the GoKGS webpage (see @CodesInChaos comment). Now it works perfectly, thanks.